# AngularJS $routeprovider Routing in Mutitab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was using this example to build the login page

[angular-authentication-example](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-authentication-example)

Once login to this app the home screen should have multi-tab view as mentioned in the below example

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuVb0mzhmDCKr1xKp7Rn?p=preview)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
  <li ng-class="tabClass(tab)" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" tab="tab"><a href="{{tab.link}}" ng-click="setSelectedTab(tab)">{{tab.label}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

The issue I am facing is the multi-tab is not embedded as Single page App. As mentioned in the demo it should embed in the same view but once I integrated, it is showing as different view. For example, when I click jobs it is taking to new html page but not included  in the same view as in the plunker demo .I want to use the angularjs route provider instead of state provider and the reason is login authentication example is best and I don't want to change the entire logic.

Comment: Hard to make any sense out of what your specific problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

***Version 1 (Without routing) [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uf4PGOrbYSx1O5zTvh3I?p=preview)***

It will redirect to a new view if you use `#/jobs` syntax. Here is a complete working solution without routes:

Your code on `plunker` is working because you didn't include `ngRoute` in your code.

View in [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uf4PGOrbYSx1O5zTvh3I?p=preview)

`app.js`

```
$scope.tabs = [
  { id : 'jobs', label : 'Jobs', templateUrl:'jobs-partial.html' },
  { id : 'invoices', label : 'Invoices',templateUrl: 'invoices-partial.html' },
  { id : 'payments', label : 'Payments',templateUrl: 'payments-partial.html' }
]; 

$scope.activeTab = $scope.tabs[0];    
$scope.changeActiveTab = function (tab) {
     $scope.activeTab = tab;
  };

$scope.isActiveTab = function (tabId) {
     return tabId === $scope.activeTab;
  }
```

Inside `index.html`

```
<body ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
  <li ng-class="{active: isActiveTab(tab.id)}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
            <a href="" ng-click="changeActiveTab(tab.id)" data-toggle="tab">{{tab.label}} </a>
          </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade" ng-class="{'in active': isActiveTab(tab.id)}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
           ng-include="tab.templateUrl">
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

***Version 2 (With routing) [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1jygyYcLZIfRQgdAKoaC?p=preview)***

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunkerApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
  </html>
```

`app.js`

```
angular
  .module('untitled4App', [
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/jobs', {
      templateUrl: '/views/jobs-partial.html',
      controller: 'JobsCtrl'
    }).when('/invoices', {
      templateUrl: '/views/invoices-partial.html',
      controller: 'InvoicesCtrl'
    }).when('/payments', {
      templateUrl: '/views/payments-partial.html',
      controller: 'PaymentsCtrl'
    });

    // make this demo work in plunker
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
  }])
  .factory('tabsService', function () {
    return {
      tabs: function () {
        return [
          {id: 'jobs', label: 'Jobs'},
          {id: 'invoices', label: 'Invoices'},
          {id: 'payments', label: 'Payments'}
        ]
      },
      activeTab: '',
      isActiveTab: function (tabId) {
        return tabId === this.activeTab;
      }
    }
  })
  .controller('JobsCtrl', ['$scope', 'tabsService', function ($scope, tabsService) {
    $scope.tabs = tabsService.tabs();
    $scope.tabsService = tabsService;

    tabsService.activeTab = $scope.tabs[0].id;

  }])
  .controller('InvoicesCtrl', ['$scope', 'tabsService', function ($scope, tabsService) {
    $scope.tabs = tabsService.tabs();
    $scope.tabsService = tabsService;

    tabsService.activeTab = $scope.tabs[1].id;

  }])
  .controller('PaymentsCtrl', ['$scope', 'tabsService', function ($scope, tabsService) {
    $scope.tabs = tabsService.tabs();
    $scope.tabsService = tabsService;

    tabsService.activeTab = $scope.tabs[2].id;
  }]);
```

`jobs.partial.html`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li ng-class="{active: tabsService.isActiveTab(tab.id)}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <a href="#/{{tab.id}}">{{tab.label}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active">
    Jobs
  </div>
</div>
```

`invoices-partial.html`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li ng-class="{active: tabsService.isActiveTab(tab.id)}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <a href="#/{{tab.id}}">{{tab.label}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active">
    Invoices
  </div>
</div>
```

`payments-partial.html`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li ng-class="{active: tabsService.isActiveTab(tab.id)}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <a href="#/{{tab.id}}">{{tab.label}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active">
    Payments
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.I agree it will redirect to a new view if you use #/jobs but it should have the tab and the view refresh based on the which tab we are clicking but in my code it is taking to the html of #jobs but the mutitab is missing in the page.

Comment: Pls provide solution implementing ngRoute ng-view

Comment: @Senthil, implemented using `ngRoute`

Comment: Appreciate your time .Unfortunately it is not working when I integrated with angular-authentication-example .Once i login It is showing only Jobs in the  landing page

Comment: How do you mean? Jobs tab is a landing page. So you can only see one tab at the same time. And when you click the different tab your route changes, and your controller, template loads. You have to fill in all the tabs' templates using the corresponding controller.

Comment: Also do not forget to copy invoices, and payments partial contents from plunker. I have provided only jobs.partial content here as an example. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks .I tried with all the code as mentioned in the plunker but the issue I am getting is "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".The plunker code works perfectly fine but as i said when integrate the github code to plunker code i am have problem.Pls check downloading the github code in my question integrate the plunker in to the github code to see how it works at your end.If it works then pls  upload the integarted code I can download and use it That helps me

Comment: Good to here. I did not havr time look at it.